# ioctlを用いた入力の検知

Tags: linux, c, ubuntu, operating-system

## ioctlについて

[組み込みLinuxデバイスドライバの作り方 (6)](https://qiita.com/iwatake2222/items/ade0a73d4c05fc7961d3#%E3%83%87%E3%83%90%E3%82%A4%E3%82%B9%E3%83%89%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%83%90%E3%81%AE%E5%AE%9F%E8%A3%85)
上記のような、ユーザープログラムで受け付けた入力を、ioctlを用いてデータのやり取りをする手法は理解できます。
実際に書いてみて、感動しました。

## ioctlについての疑問

入力を受け付けるプログラムが存在し、そのプログラムのfdをioctlの第一引数として指定すると、ioctlでそのプログラムが受け付けた入力を盗み見することは可能になるのでしょうか？

悪用ができるとなると、使い方に気をつけないといけないな、と思いました。

最近勉強をし始めたので、浅はかな知識しか持ち合わせていないので、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: `ioctl`の第一引数はファイルディスクリプターですが、質問内容は合っていますか? (通常はデバイスファイルを`open`した結果を指定するかと)

Comment: ファイルディスクリプタでした。
修正しました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

質問のような、「そのプログラムが受け付けた入力を盗み見すること」は不可能と思います。
以下、理由。

1. 起動したプロセスは、ファイルディスクリプターでは管理されない。
2. 実行プログラムを`open`してファイルディスクリプターを取得しても、それを実行することはできない。

Comment: ありがとうございます。